# Inflections: How to use custom acronyms when creating new application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

Let’s say I’m working on a product called Friendly Organizational Operator, for which we use FOO as the acronym. I want to create a new engine to encapsulate a particular piece of functionality we’ll call Bar (I used all my creativity on that first one). Naturally, my engine will be called foo-bar with a namespaced name of foo/bar. However, the root module name will be Foo, when in reality I’d really like it to be FOO. For example:

```
$ rails plugin new foo-bar --mountable
  create  
  create  README.md
  create  Rakefile
  create  foo-bar.gemspec
  create  MIT-LICENSE
  create  .gitignore
  <...snip...>

$ cat foo-bar/lib/foo/bar/engine.rb 
module Foo
  module Bar
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      isolate_namespace Foo::Bar
    end
  end
end
```

I realize that I need to actually tell Rails about this acronym. Generally, I do that with an initializer in the engine:

```rb
module FOO
  module Bar
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      isolate_namespace FOO::Bar

      initializer 'setup_inflections' do
        ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
          inflect.acronym 'FOO'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then the rest falls into place just fine (e.g. autoloading). Of course, I need to run a big sed search/replace on the entire engine first.

So here's my question: is there a way to generate that initial engine using the proper acronym off the bat instead of needing to sed after I've created it? As it happens I'm using application templates anyway, so I'm just doing the sed in there, but I'm not a huge fan. Can I tell Rails about my acronym before it generates the engine? Perhaps there is some functionality in the application template API that I've missed? A hook that might run before the actual generation, maybe (otherwise my template always runs after the engine is already generated)?

Comment: theoretically you could use `rails plugin new f_o_o-bar` but then your directories will reflect "f_o_o/bar" (which is likely to be equally undesirable).

Comment: @engineersmnky yep :`(

Comment: I think you could do it by creating your own customized [plugin generator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c88ca3b72083449fd242ed5aaf1b557f88a9e7b2/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/plugin/plugin_generator.rb) which you put in a gem. But are you actually doing this often enough for it to be worth the effort?

Comment: @max maybe I decide to customize the plugin generator. How does it work?

Comment: I really haven't actually looked at how you would do it practically - I'm really just spitballing here. All the generators are kind of made to be extended/subclassed such you should be a able to figure out how it it works from looking at the source - you could probally hook into the initialize method or something and setup your inflection or make it take an additonal option for the constant name.